# Increment "main" property in package.json as well as "version"

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm used to using

```
npm version major | minor | patch
```

to increment the version number in package.json.

For a project I'm working on, the "main" property in package.json also contains the version number e.g.

```
{
   "name": "MyAmazingPackage",
   "version": "2.1.6",
   "main": "dist/main-2.1.6"
}
```

How can I increment the version in "main" at the same time?

Comment: I don't think `npm version` will have the capability to do this; a Node or batch script may be easiest (I would go with a Node script because it'd be trivially easy to manipulate the JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
npm version major | sed "s|v||" | read version; sed "s|\"\(dist/main-\).*\"|\"\1$version\"|" package.json > _package.json; mv _package.json package.json
```

- Bump version (major/minor/patch)
- Remove the `v`
- Replace `dist/main-2.1.6` with the resulting version
- Replace `package.json` with the output

Comment: This does assume quite a bit about the OP's environment.